# MEF and Unity integration

Tags: unity-container, mef

I have an application where I use MEF for composition and unity for DI.
At some point, I have a component that uses MEF to load many providers for a sevice.
Some if the providers should be instantiated using Unity, because they need to receive add'l components when instantiated.

The provider needed to be created by Unity had the dependency types / interfaces registered with the container.

But when the root component is composed through MEF, (and the list is filled with all exported components registered by MEF), the one that needs build up with Unity doesn't get its dependencies injected.

My code is

```
public class LoggerManager
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(ILogger))]
    private List<ILogger> _loggers { get; set; }
}
```

and a logger is

```
[Export(typeof(ILogger))]
public class WinEventLog : EventLog, ILogger
{

    private IWinLoggerConfigurator _config = null;

    public WinEventLog(IWinLoggerConfigurator config)
    {
        _config=config;
    }
}
```

In my main code I have, before attempting to compose LogManager

```
UnityHelper.Container.RegisterType<IWinLoggerConfigurator , MyWinLoggerConfigurator>();
```

How this can be accomplished?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should also check out this MEFContrib project - http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity%20Integration

Answer (score 0):

I found the following post, that described the situation, and a solution to it.

http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2009/05/unity-mef-integration-layer.html